# How to get VLD log of another process?

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-leaks, visual-leak-detector

Main process creates another, that uses the same executable with another args.

```
cmdline = "\"c:\\path\\executable.exe\" arg1 arg2";
CreateProcess(NULL, cmdline, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

So, i set those configs in vld.ini:

```
StackWalkMethod = safe
ReportTo = both
```

In this case VLD creates report file only for main process, i.e. created process doesn't writes to log file (i think main process holds it). But in visual studio i have information about leaks in created process in output window while attached to created process.

My question is how i can switch debugger output to file in another process?

Comment: Just a guess, maybe it simply cannot find config because working directory changed? have you tried to set it manually in `lpCurrentDirectory` argument of `CreateProcess`?